# How do I make a function in python that takes a string as an argument and returns all possible upper case and lower case combination of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

****Problem**** : To make a function which takes string as an argument and return every possible combination which can be made through switching upper / lower cases.

****Example****  :

Argument : "a" 
Returns : ["a", "A"]

Argument : "aB" 
Returns : ["ab", "Ab", "aB", " AB"]

Comment: Hi! You should try something, and then post your [mcve] with any errors so we can help with specific problems (you already have the "input and expected output" part, just add some code :) )

Comment: Use a combination of upper and lower method with itertools.product. it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` along with `zip`:

```
def combs(s):
    return list(map(''.join, product(*zip(s.lower(), s.upper()))))
```

Example:

```
>>> combs('a')
['a', 'A']
>>> combs('ab')
['ab', 'aB', 'Ab', 'AB']
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
def getlist(word):
list = []
for x in range(2**len(word)):
    x = bin(x).replace("0b", "")
    while len(x) < len(word):
        x="0"+x
    s = ""
    for letter in range(len(word)):
        if x[letter] =="1":
            s+= word[letter].upper()
        else:
            s+=word[letter].lower()
    list.append(s)
return list
```